# ElasticSearch :: Exception while ceating index and document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch & was trying to execute the example mentioned in their home page where I came across this erorr -

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.mappings.employee.properties.age.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unknown setting [index.mappings.employee.properties.age.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings",
        "suppressed": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.mappings.employee.properties.experience.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            },
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.mappings.employee.properties.name.analyzer] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            },
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unknown setting [index.mappings.employee.properties.name.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

The url & body of the post request are as follows -

URL - > http://localhost:9200/company
BODY - >

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
       "number_of_shards": 1,
       "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "analyzer-name": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "employee": {
        "properties": {
          "age": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "experience": {
            "type": "long"      
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "analyzer-name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

How to fix the error ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two errors in syntax of your JSON body object:

1. Node `settings` must have only two childs: `index` and `analysis`. Node `mappings` must be root-level.
2. Field `name` has invalid type `string`, it must be `text` or `keyword`. Because you need this field to be analyzed, it should be `text` in your case.

So working query **for ES version 6.x** (that was current at the time of the question) should be like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
       "number_of_shards": 1,
       "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "analyzer-name": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "employee": {
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "experience": {
          "type": "long"      
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "analyzer-name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Starting from ES version 7.0, mapping types [was removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) from index definition, so the query above wouldn't work in ES 7.x.

Working query **for ES version 7.x** could be two types:

1. If index should contain data only about employees, you can simply delete `employee` mapping type and query would be like this:

   ```
   {
     "settings": {
       "index": {
         "number_of_shards": 1,
         "number_of_replicas": 1
       },
       "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
           "analyzer-name": {
             "type": "custom",
             "tokenizer": "keyword",
             "filter": "lowercase"
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "mappings": {
       "properties": {
         "age": {
           "type": "long"
         },
         "experience": {
           "type": "long"      
         },
         "name": {
           "type": "text",
           "analyzer": "analyzer-name"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. If index should contain data about employees and some other data, you can use `employee` as field of the [object type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) and query would be like this:

   ```
   {
     "settings": {
       "index": {
         "number_of_shards": 1,
         "number_of_replicas": 1
       },
       "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
           "analyzer-name": {
             "type": "custom",
             "tokenizer": "keyword",
             "filter": "lowercase"
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "mappings": {
       "properties": {
         "employee": {
           "properties": {
             "age": {
               "type": "long"
             },
             "experience": {
               "type": "long"      
             },
             "name": {
               "type": "text",
               "analyzer": "analyzer-name"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: @user3898336, what version of Elasticsearch do you use? I verify my answer on `6.*` (which was relevant at the time of writing the answer) and it works, but now relevant version is `7.*` and there are many breaking changes between these versions.

Comment: Hi @SameeraDeSilva, I updated my answer with examples for ES version 7.x. Original example doesn't work in 7.x due to [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) between 6.x and 7.x.

Answer (score 1):

```
As you mentioned that you are new to Elastic Search, better start with the basic and use the default settings of ElasticSearch. Use the following mapping:

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/company -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "employee": {
            "properties": {
                "age": {"type": "long"},
                "experience": {"type": "long"},
                "name": {"type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Note that your example will work only for versions of Elasticsearch prior to 5.0, because of [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) in syntax - datatype `string` was splitted in `text` and `keyword` datatypes.